# Is there a way to check which order symbols are loaded into an application in linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I know that there is the /proc/proc#/maps file that shows the libraries that are loaded, but is there a way to find out in which order the symbols are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all sorts of debug information using the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable.  For example:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=files ls
```

This will execute `ls` and show you the shared libraries as they are loaded.  Use `LD_DEBUG=help` for a list of other options.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the app under `strace` and watch dynamic linker `mmap` the libraries into process memory.

Comment: is there a better way to see only the mmap stuff since strace spits out a lot of data and it's hard to go through it all, even if I | grep mmap....?

Comment: the -e mmap option filters for just mmap.

Comment: I think you should accept @mark4o's answer - I totally forgot about the LD_DEBUG - it actually allows you to watch libraries loaded, symbols processing, bindings, etc.